# how to fetch data for particular values from a column among different values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Example related to my requirement.
I have a table t_policies_details
columns  pol_ref , inrtyp

```
inrtyp has values = ORD,PPC,AVCO,DSS,RVP, SP,TV
```

I want to fetch polref for which inrtyp is only SP and TV both , no any other.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref, p.inrtyp FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('ORD')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref, p.inrtyp FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('PPC')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref, p.inrtyp FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('AVCO')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref, p.inrtyp FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('DSS')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref, p.inrtyp FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('RVP')
```

I have tried with above query, exclusing things which are not required, 
    but this gives me polref, which has either SP or TV , or both. I have to search again which has both.
    I found few by searching.
    But when I included the condition:

```
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref, p.inrtyp FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp IN ('SP')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref, p.inrtyp FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp IN ('TV')
```

I don't get any polref.

Please help me to get this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all instances where a `polref` has `inrtyp` for both 'TV', 'SP' but no other values at all. You can count the number of wanted and unwanted instances in a group by, and then apply logic in an outer select:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT p.polref,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.inrtyp IN ('TV', 'SP') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Good, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.inrtyp NOT IN ('TV', 'SP') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Bad
  FROM t_policies_details p
  GROUP BY p.polref
)
SELECT cte.polref
FROM cte
WHERE Good = 2 AND Bad = 0;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c89c1/7)

Answer (score 0):

remove `p.inrtyp` from your selected list of columns and that will do it. If you're using a column in the where clause it doesn't have to appear in the selected list of columns. You'll get a list of pol_refs which match your condition

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('ORD')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('PPC')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('AVCO')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('DSS')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp NOT IN ('RVP')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp IN ('SP')
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref FROM t_policies_details p WHERE p.inrtyp IN ('TV')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query. This may be helping you

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.polref, p.inrtyp
FROM t_policies_details p
WHERE p.inrtyp = ALL ('SP','TV');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query.

Query:

SELECT DISTINCT p.polref, p.inrtyp
FROM t_policies_details p
WHERE p.inrtyp in ('SP','TV');